# Restrict Swipe Controls

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing an endless runner game where you swipe left and right on a road to move the player between lanes. I want to restrict my lower screen proportion (not large proportion, small proportion).

How can you disable the touch or swipe controls in a specific area?